# Codeigniter: Loop in start_transaction

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, transactions

I'm using for loop in a transaction. I have a question about this loop. While it's inserting e.x 100 rows to database, among inserting, if another person wants to insert, does it make problem, or `insert_id()` won't change? Thanks.

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO category (Cat_Name, Subname, IsActive, Description)
                                VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", array($Cat_Name, $Sub_Name, $IsActive, $Description));
$last_id_cat = $this->db->insert_id();
for ($i=-1; $i < $arr_count; $i++) {        
    $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO feature_ref (Cat_ID, Feature_ID)
                                VALUES(?, ?)", array($last_id_cat, $Feature[$i]));
}
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **won't** effect anything.

Suppose your loop has started say from 1 and now reached at position say 15 so the `id's` inserted in the table would be 1-15 and now some other person added another row and the `id` moves ahead to 16 and now your continuous loop will add the 17th row and now `$this->db->insert_id();` will surely give you 17 and not 16.

Hence a straight answer, **no**. Your loop will work perfectly and it won't affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

will give you last id generated in database.

when you use `$this->db->insert_id();` exact below your query it will give you perfect result because query will run one by one.
so you can you this rather finding another solution.

Comment: So, What should I do to prevent affecting other queries in same time? I'm not sure due to transaction.

Comment: Please correct. `$this->db->insert_id();` gives you last id generated.

Comment: @Ronak And it will not effect.